# How can I trigger an Operation Aborted error in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I've gotten reports of Operation Aborted errors from some developers who are using a JavaScript plugin and I'm trying to reproduce the problem to make a good recommendation for how they can fix their usage. I think the issue is that they are calling into DOM modifying functions from within the container that they'll be modifying. In those cases the plugin will be doing something equivalent to this

```
<div id="a">
  <script>
    document.getElementById('a').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  </script>
</div>
```

I've seen this given as an example that will trigger an Operation Aborted error in IE7 but when I try it, everything seems to work fine. I'm using IE version 7.0.6002.18005, do I need an older version to trigger this behavior? Is there another way to trigger this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on a version of IE6 and was able to trigger operation aborted with the following HTML.

```
<html>  
  <body>  
    <div> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var newElem = document.createElement('foo'); 
        document.body.appendChild(newElem); 
      </script> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

I guess newer versions of IE7 have been patched to fix this issue.